# Django processing form input name

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have changed the input's name attribute to some custom name, but the view calls **form_invalid** method. Why my Form isn't saving (validating)?

html:

```
<tr>
      <th><label for="id_photo">Image:</label></th>
      <td>
      <input type="file" name="custom_photo_name" accept="image/*" required id="id_photo" multiple>
      </td>
</tr>
```

the line in view:

```
self.request.FILES.getlist('custom_photo_name')
```

Doesn't the self.request.FILES takes the values according to **name** attribute?

Comment: What method are you using to send your request: GET/POST?

Comment: I am using POST method